# Find a diffeomorphism $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $F(x)=y$

Tags: diffeomorphism

Suppose $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n $. Find a diffeomorphism $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$ such that $F(x)=y$ and $F(z)=z$ for any $z\in \mathbb{R}^n-B(x,r)$ .

Comment: This need that $r\geq \vert x-y\vert$. Can you do it in diemension 1 ?

Comment: I can prove the case for dim=1,but not for dim>1